# How do i get my divs to sity side by side

Tags: css

I cant seem to get my navigation div (which is on the left) to sit directly next to my content div (which is on the right).

They both sit in the wrapper div. I have done this on an external style sheet in CSS.

Comment: please post your code on http://jsfiddle.net that would be much comfortable to understand your exact problem........

Comment: Can you please give us jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 4):

This is something you could try:

```
<style>
    #div1, #div2 {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is something interesting. Can you please add explanation who it will differ from float?

Comment: Using inline-block will give you better control over the number of divs you can have within the wrapper and their positioning.

Comment: I would add that inline-block will treat your element as an inline element but still let you set some block element properties like width and height.

Answer (score 2):

You can use floats or change it's "display" property to "inline-block". Sometimes the second option is better for you, so you don't mess with floats (since it looks you're only starting with CSS).

Also, if you share with us your code or website link, it's a lot easier for us to help you. If you don't do that, we're are blind here trying to help you (including me).

Comment: #nav ul {
float: left;
clear:both;
}

#content {
float: top-right;




}

#wrapper {
background-color:#fff;
border: 1px solid #464683;
border-left: none;
border-top: none;
width: 1000px;
height: 800px;
margin: 30px auto;
padding: 0;
border-radius: 0 0 100px 40px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 100px 40px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 100px 40px;
overflow: hidden;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #555;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #555;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #555;

Comment: This is just CSS. It doesn't help much, but check your #content float. "top-right" won't work. You should "float: right;" instead. Also, try not "clear: both;" on your "#nav ul" unless you have a wide nav and you don't want anything sitting besides it. Do you really need to set a fixed height of your #wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

Use floating.
Take a look here
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Keep in mind to use

> clear

when you use float.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can try `position: absolute;` and give both divs their positions manually.

Comment: Positioning my mess with cross browser, he need to be so careful to use the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can float them both, and it's better to specify their widths either by `px` or percentage. Like this:

   div1{
       float: left;
       width: 200px;
       }
       div2{
       float: left;
       width: 600px;
       }
2. You can just float one, and use `margin` property to place the second
   div properly.
3. You can also apply `display: absolute` to both divs to get what you want.
4. Better yet, you can use something like [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) to help you do this
   by grid layout. It can be very handy. Nevertheless, I think it's good to know basic `css` knowledge.

---

If you want your layout to be fluid, don't use 3 or 2.

**EDIT**:

A little bit advice: I think you can find a web page which is close to what you want(there are plenty) and read the relevant css code for it, look up all the css property along the way.

Comment: Here is my css code - i am doing it on an external style sheet

Answer (score 0):

You can use float for this, Please use float wisely.

Code can be as mentioned below

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="right">Right</div>
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="clearfloat"></div> <!--To romove floats-->
</div>​

.wrapper{
width:500px;
height:100px;
color:#FFF;
}
.right{
width:30%;
background-color:red;
float:left;
}

.left{
width:70%;
background-color:blue;
float:left;
}

.clearfloat{
clear:both
}
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/PJhst/1/

Comment: #nav ul {
float: left;
clear:both;
}

#content {
float: top-right;




}

#wrapper {
background-color:#fff;
border: 1px solid #464683;
border-left: none;
border-top: none;
width: 1000px;
height: 800px;
margin: 30px auto;
padding: 0;
border-radius: 0 0 100px 40px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 100px 40px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 100px 40px;
overflow: hidden;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #555;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #555;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #555;

Comment: #nav ul {
float: left;
clear:both;
}

#content {
float: top-right;




}

#wrapper {
background-color:#fff;
border: 1px solid #464683;
border-left: none;
border-top: none;
width: 1000px;
height: 800px;
margin: 30px auto;
padding: 0;
border-radius: 0 0 100px 40px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 100px 40px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 100px 40px;
overflow: hidden;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #555;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #555;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #555;

Comment: Could you please explain what is reason to use float and clear for same element ?

Comment: @LeanneTaylor For one, you are not using `clear` the right way.

Answer (score 0):

A few of the example here make me want to cry.

For starters, do NOT use `inline-block` This will lead to all sorts of cross browser difficulties with width calculations. Floating the columns is definitely the best way to go.

Your markup can be done as simply as this.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Container div that will prevent the child divs from breaking the layout 
of the page for content below-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="clmn">
    <!-- First column -->
    </div>
    <div class="clmn">
    <!-- Second column -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/**
 * Columns
 * 1. The column is floated left which pushes the div as far left as it can 
      possibly go within it's parent container.
 * 2. The width of the container is set at less than 50% so that you can leave 
      a gap between the columns.
 */

.clmn{
    float:left; /* 1 */
    width:49%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * 1. The selector identifies any container with the class `.clmn` which has 
      another column before it. A margin is added to that to create the space. 
      This is calculated at 100% - (2 * 49% )
 */

.clmn + .clmn{
    margin-left:2%; /* 1 */
}

/* Clearfix to contain floats. 
  See http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ 
 */

/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.container:before,
.container:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.container:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.container {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

The beauty of the method is that you can expand on it to handle columns of different width easily. I use a more complete system all the time at work and have open sourced the approach in a grid system. [here](http://jimbobsquarepants.github.com/Flexo/)